Getting 404 from ReadItemAsync cosmosdb client in .net
I've been trying figuring out how to setup a cosmos db client in .net web api, and not far enough.
I've noticed when using the cosmosdb ReadItemAsync function I always get 404 back with this response

With the following code:
public async Task<OkObjectResult> All()
{
    var client = CosmosService.GetClient();
    var container = client.GetDatabase("Development").GetContainer("Notes");

    var result = await container.ReadItemAsync<CosmosNote>("1717482138", new PartitionKey("id"));
    return Ok(result);
}

I have also tried using a different function. I have tried using ReadManyItemsAsync, which surprisingly work for some weird reason!
public async Task<OkObjectResult> All()
{
    var client = CosmosService.GetClient();
    var container = client.GetDatabase("Development").GetContainer("Notes");

    List<(string, PartitionKey)> itemsToFind = new()
    {
        ("1717482138", new PartitionKey("id"))
    };

    var data = await container.ReadManyItemsAsync<CosmosNote>(itemsToFind);
    return Ok(data);
}

I don't get it why ReadItemAsync isn't working, can anyone help?
Thanks!
Edit:
Cosmos data explorer in azure


In the PartitionKey you need to use the value and not the property name. If you change it to:
var partition = new PartitionKey("1717482138"); //<- value instead of property
var result = await container.ReadItemAsync<CosmosNote>("1717482138", partition);

It should work assuming you're using the /id as your partition in your Cosmos container.
